# Excel VBA Code Error - Argument Not Found (Generating a Query if clicks Button)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently creating a function in VBA that generates a query automatically if you press a button. The code runs without error, initially, but when I fill out the input boxes correctly, it gives me the error, application-defined or object-defined error (Error 1004). In the code, I reference to an excel sheet which pulls certain information from the report (specifically the columns) and creates a query using these columns where the month and year are a certain date. Then, I aim to move the query to a different Excel workbook, and list them in a sheet over there. However, I continue to receive the same error (The place of error is on the .QueryTable.CommandText = query line...*). This is the code :

```
Sub GenerateQuery()
    ' Get user inputs
    Dim targetMonth As String
    targetMonth = InputBox("Enter the target month (e.g., January):")
    
    

    Select Case LCase(targetMonth)
     Case "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"
           ' Valid month entered
     Case Else
         MsgBox "Please enter a valid month name."
         ' Prompt user for input again or exit the code, based on your requirement
         Exit Sub ' Exits the sub-routine
    End Select
    Dim targetYear As String
    targetYear = InputBox("Enter the target year (e.g., 2023):")
    
 
    If Not IsNumeric(targetYear) Or Len(targetYear) <> 4 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid year format. Please enter a four-digit year.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub ' Exit the code if input is invalid
    End If
    ' Define the list of column names to include in the query result
    Dim columnList As String
    columnList = "[Invoice Id], [Invoice Date], FORMAT([Invoice Date], ""mmm-dd"") AS [Formatted Date], [Serial], [Purch Id], [Item Id], [Sell Price], [Revenue Share], [Vendor]"


    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT " & columnList & " FROM [tbl_Cons_Rpt] WHERE MONTH([Invoice Date]) = " & Month(DateValue(targetMonth & " 1")) & " AND YEAR([Invoice Date]) = " & targetYear & " AND [Vendor] = 'V005501 - Atlantic Broadband ARP'"
 
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\notgoingtoshow.xlsx")

    targetWorkbook.Sheets("qry_ABB1").UsedRange.ClearContents

    Dim tableDestination As Range
    Set tableDestination = targetWorkbook.Sheets("qry_ABB1").Range("A1")

    With targetWorkbook.Sheets("qry_ABB1").ListObjects.Add( _
                                     SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
                                     Source:=tableDestination, _
                                     XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes)
       .Name = "qry_ABB1"
       .QueryTable.CommandText = query
       .QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ' Save and close the target workbook
    targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True ' Modify as needed (e.g., save changes or not)
End Sub
```

Can anyone identify what seems to be the problem?

Comment: `ListObjects.Add` doesn't have an argument named `HasHeaders` it has `XlListObjectHasHeaders`

Comment: Always helps to tell use *where* you get the error, rather than have us all guess.

Comment: @TimWilliams Doesn't tell me where the error is found thats the problem. The error happens AFTER that code is run.

Comment: So there's no "debug" button when the error pops up?

Comment: @Toddleson Hey! Thanks for the help. Still gives the same problem though, named argument not found :(

Comment: @TimWilliams No unfortunately not. It continues to give me this error : Named argument not found (Error 448) with an ok button and a help buttons. I've tried debugging the code to see where the error occurred but no errors showed up.

Comment: In your VBA options make sure you have "Break in class module" set under *Tools >> Options >> General >> Error trapping*

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the help! Located the error its in the line:
 With targetWorkbook.Sheets("qry_ABB1").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcQuery, Source:=query, Destination:=tableDestination, XListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes). Do you have any ideas what the problem could me?

Comment: It's `XlListObjectHasHeaders` not `XListObjectHasHeaders`

Comment: @TimWilliams Fixed it but still received an error, this time application-defined or object-defined error (Run-time error 1004) on the same line.

Comment: You may be mis-using the `Source` parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add#:~:text=When%20SourceType%20%3D%20xlSrcQuery%3A%20Accepts%20ODBC%20or%20OLEDB%20connection%20string%20(this%20also%20works%20with%20xlSrcExternal)   It should be a connection string, not a SQL query

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the help. Edited the code as seen in my post. Now receiving an error with the .QueryTable.CommandText line. Same error as before...Error 1004.

Comment: What connection string are you using? Is it in `tableDestination`? Maybe that driver doesn't support use of (eg) `FORMAT()` /  Try subbing in a much simpler query and see if that works.

Comment: @TimWilliams Not sure what you mean by connection string. The query comes from the excel workbook that I'm coming from, its in the table that I've referenced. On the otherhand, the tableDestination is where I'm storing the query (theres not actually a query in there yet). Do I need to create a connection string and if so how? Tried using it without the FORMAT(), and still received error